# Writing a byte[] as a mp3 file

Tags: c#, .net, mp3

This is what I am doing, I read an `.mp3` file convert it into a `Base64String` this way:

```
using (fileStream)
{ 
  fileStreamLength = (int)fileStream.Length + 1;
  fileInBytes = new byte[fileStreamLength];
  int currbyte = 0, i = 0;
  while (currbyte != -1)
  {
  currbyte = fileStream.ReadByte();
  fileInBytes[i++] = (byte)currbyte;
  }
}
    
string fileInString = Convert.ToBase64String(fileInBytes);
```

Now after some work I again have the same `Base64String` which I will convert into bytes through `byte[] asBytesAgain = Convert.FromBase64String(fileInString);`

Now my question how can I write this `byte[]` as an `.mp3` file to be played?

Answer (score 9):

```
File.WriteAllBytes("somefile.mp3", asBytesAgain);
```

Comment: It creates an mp3 file but when we run it on media player it gives an error and does not play the file.

Comment: @SalmanLone `File.WriteAllBytes` will only write the bytes in your array to disk. If the bytearray does not constitute a valid mp3 file, the problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: i am using ReadAllBytes(file); for the bytes and then do some operation for converting it from mono to stereo and then call WriteAllBytes

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks so much for giving a one line solution to write out my bytes!